# implement timeout in Rust

Tags: rust, zeromq

Looking for a clean way to implement a timeout wrapper on my zmq receiver in rust. Any general advice on my code would also be welcomed this is my 3rd day in exploring rust.

```rust
pub struct Manager {
  conn: zmq::Socket,
  server: String,
}

impl Manager {
  pub async fn send_message(
    self: &Self,
    subject: String,
    queue: String,
    message: json::JsonValue,
  ) -> json::JsonValue {
    let mut msg = zmq::Message::new();

    let data = object! {
      messageID: Ulid::new().to_string(),
      requester: self.server.to_string(),
      subject: subject,
      queue: queue,
      payload: message,
    };

    self.conn.send(&data.dump(), 0).unwrap();
    self.conn.recv(&mut msg, 0).unwrap();
    println!("Message Received {}", msg.as_str().unwrap());

    match msg.as_str() {
      Some(response) => json::parse(response).unwrap(),
      None => json::parse(r#" { "status": "error", "error": "unable to parse data" } "#).unwrap(),
    }
  }
}
```

And then calling it from a different package

```rust
let resp: json::JsonValue = messager
    .send_message("subject".to_string(), "queue".to_string(), data)
    .await;
```

Ideally I'm looking for a clean way to and a `i8` to my caller function, then having something like

```rust
pub async fn send_message(
    self: &Self,
    subject: String,
    queue: String,
    message: json::JsonValue,
    timeout: i8, // timeout in seconds
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`async_std::future::timeout`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.5.0/async_std/future/fn.timeout.html). When you have `Manager::send_message` implemented that it is sending the data without timeout, you can wrap in the following way:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use async_std::future;

let send_message_fut = messager
    .send_message("subject".to_string(), "queue".to_string(), data);

let dur = Duration::from_millis(5);
match future::timeout(dur, send_message_fut).await {
   Ok(resp) => {
      // ...
   },
   Err(err) => {
      // ...
   }
}
```